# Sort a list by a function results

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, reflection

I want to sort a list by the results of functions that are contained in list items. How would go about doing that?

Here is an example. Let's say I have a following object:

```
Public Class MyListObject
    Public MyText1 As String
    Public MyText2 As String

    Public Function AddSuffix(ByVal MySuffix As String) As String
        Return Mytext1 & MySuffix
    End Function

End Class
```

(massively oversimplified for the sake of example)

After that I have a list of these objects:

```
Dim ResultList As New List(Of MyListObject)
```

Now, for example, to sort the list by the field `MyText1` value, I used this:

```
ResultList = ResultList.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType(MyListObject).GetField("MyText1").GetValue(x)).ToList
```

(used reflection, so I can pass the field name as a string)

How can I sort this list by the function `AddSuffix` result and simultaneously pass the parameter `MySuffix`?

I imagine it would look something like this, but obviously this doesn't work

```
ResultList = ResultList.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType(MyListObject).GetField("AddSuffix(""_myCustomSuffix"")").GetValue(x)).ToList
```

PS. I realize, that in this example the function is pretty much meaningless. The actual code is much more complex and that function does return different sortable data for each list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have a pretty good reason to use reflection, but I would recommend avoiding it even if you have too many fields and methods.

```
ResultList = ResultList.OrderBy(Function(o) o.AddSuffix("_myCustomSuffix")).ToList
```

The VB way of calling a method by name is something like this (also not tested)

```
ResultList = ResultList.OrderBy(Function(o) CallByName(o,
                        "AddSuffix", CallType.Method, "_myCustomSuffix")).ToList
```

Comment: Wow. That was much easier than I thought. Both examples work for my case. Thank you!!
Initially I used reflection in order to sort by field value - I needed to somehow pass the field name as a string. But for this case I just figured out, that I only need to pass the argument for the function and not the function name it self. And therefore there is no need for reflection. Yay.